# How to use excel to get permutations of “Yes” and “No” across 6 columns?

Tags: excel, vba, combinations, permutation

Can you please tell me how I am able to get all of the permutations of yes and no across 6 columns?

A similar question was asked, and the following formula was provided for 5 columns:

```
=CHOOSE(1+MID(LEFT("00000",5-LEN(DEC2BIN(32-ROW()+1)))&DEC2BIN(32-ROW()+1),COLUMN()-1,1),"No","Yes")
```

The following VBA response was provided for 5 columns:

```
Option Explicit 
Sub DisplayYesNoPerms()
Dim rows&, cols&
cols = 5
rows = 2 ^ cols
[b2].Resize(rows cols) = YesNoPerms(rows, cols)
End Sub
Function YesNoPerms(rows&, cols&)
Dim i&, j&, t$, v
ReDim v(0 To rows -1, 1 To cols)
For i=0 To rows - 1
t= Format(DecToBin(i), String(cols, "0"))
For j=1 To cols
v(i, j) = IIf(Mid(t, j, 1), "No", "Yes")
Next
Next
YesNoPerms = v
End Function
Function DecToBin$(ByVal n&)
Do 
DecToBin = n Mod 2 & DecToBin
n = n \ 2
Loop While n
End Function
```

Bonus logic:

- If column 1 is no, column 2 cannot be yes.
- If column 3 is no, column 4 cannot be yes.
- If column 5 is no, column 6 cannot be yes.

Comment: Have you tagged VBA for a particular reason? Do you have code you forgot to include in your question?

Comment: I have added the VBA code above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also based on Binary Patterns:

```
Sub qwerty()
    Dim i As Long, wf As WorksheetFunction
    Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction
    With wf
        For i = 0 To 63
            arr = Split(Replace(Replace(frag(.Dec2Bin(i, 6)), "1", "yes"), "0", "no"), ",")
            Range(Cells(i + 1, 1), Cells(i + 1, 6)).Value = arr
        Next i
    End With
End Sub

Public Function frag(sin As String) As String
    Dim i As Long, L As Long
    frag = Left(sin, 1)
    L = Len(sin)
    If L = 1 Then Exit Function
    For i = 2 To L
        frag = frag & "," & Mid(sin, i, 1)
    Next i
End Function
```

`Frag()` converts a string into a comma-separated string.

[image]